# Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 128, with triplet loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I'm try to use the triplet loss with a CNN, I first implemented a small network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Lambda, Flatten
from keras import optimizers
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None),  # No activation on final dense layer
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))  # L2 normalize embeddings
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())
```

My input are generators with size (128,224,224,3) and my labels (128), it works fine, but when I try to use the same input and labels with inceptionV3 with imagenet weights, I get this error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 128
     [[node loss_5/lambda_4_loss/TripletSemiHardLoss/weighted_loss/Squeeze (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_111397]
```

This is my code, I use the same layers and the same input but it doesn't work.

```
base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
x_top = base_model.output
x_out = Flatten()(x_top)
x_out = Dense(256, name='nactivation', activation=None)(x_out)
x_out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x_out)
model = Model(base_model.input, x_out)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss(), metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(
            generator=train_data_gen,
            use_multiprocessing=True,
            steps_per_epoch=200,
            epochs=5,
```

If I change the batch size of my generator, for example 64, this is the new error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 64
         [[node loss_5/lambda_4_loss/TripletSemiHardLoss/weighted_loss/Squeeze (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_111397]
```

I don't know why the error is associated with the batch size

Comment: Why not try with batch size of 1 and see what happens

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with Data Pre-Processing and how Generators are defined, because I can run your `Network` successfully on my `Data`. Can you please share complete code so that I can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I can solve the problem, and is a problem with how I call the libraries, the best practice to use keras in TF is directly using tf.keras.*. more information: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/1783

Answer (score 0):

Answering here for the benefit of the community since the user has already found the solution.

The issue was with the inconsistency in the import of libraries, changing the importing changes `from keras import library_name`  to `from tf.keras import library_name` resolves the issue.

You can follow this link to the [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13khyT64lIYiZx_SJIT9GPOiFfJuwXgWT?usp=sharing) from **WindQAQ**  for the above implementation.